# TFS max check-in files limitation

Tags: c#, api, tfs

I'm using TFS API to manage versions of my application's data.
In the first use i'm trying to convert all the data base data to the TFS workspace and then the check-in stuck for long time (can take more than hour if it not stuck forever), i'm dealing with 100,000-200,000 files to check-in.
There is any limitation in TFS of number of check-in files? if not, what can be the bottle neck of this operation?
Split the check in to small packages of files would help? if so, any recommended bulk size?

Comment: Your project use 150k files ?!

Comment: its not code files... its database rows

Comment: So you, correct me if I'm wrong, export the database to file (1 row => 1 file), then use versionning with TFS to keep track of it. Is that correct ?

Comment: Why not just export each table as a CSV for something? Or a file with generated insert statements. 200k files are going to be impossible to maintain.

Comment: The creation of the file its not the problem here, the bottle neck here is the check-in operation (this scenario occurred once when start versionning). manage file as table of CSV is not an option.

Comment: No, the problem is to try to check-in a database, no matter the file settings you choose. Save your database as `.sql` or `.whatever` but please, for the sake of your computer & TFS, don't version it that way.

Comment: This is the wrong way to go about  versioning database data.

Answer (score 0):

> The number of changes in a changeset is stored as the CLR's `int` type.
>   So there's definitely an upper limit of `int.MaxValue` or `2,147,483,647`.

More details you can refer the answer from Edward in this question:[Is there a limit on the number of files in a changeset in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054306/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-files-in-a-changeset-in-tfs)

In other words, you are far from the check-in limitation. Check in process aborted may relate the network connection and current system load.

---

Moreover, just like above mentioned in the comment. It's not recommend to check in and version control database data file in TFS. Suggest you to create a script. Here is also a discussion about it: [Do you use source control for your database items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115369/do-you-use-source-control-for-your-database-items)

> The databases themselves? No
>
> The scripts that create them, including static data inserts, stored
>   procedures and the like; of course. They're text files, they are
>   included in the project and are checked in and out like everything
>   else.